# Amazon S3 Requester Pays Buckets not requesting the user pay

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to setup an Amazon S3 bucket so users can download files from a webpage but they pay for the download not me. I created a bucket selected Requester Pays Bucket. I have PHP code to generate a link for the user to download the file. However when I test the link the file starts downloading without asking the testing user to pay. I saw on the documentation site to add "x-amz-request-payer:requester" to the link but in seemed to have no effect. Any help would be great.

Here is my code to generate the link:

```
$string = sprintf("GET\n\n\n%s\n%s\n/%s/%s", $time, "x-amz-request-payer:requester" ,$bucket, $pathToObject);
// Generate an HMAC-SHA1 signature for it
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $string, $secretKey, true));
// Create the final URL
return sprintf(
"https://s3.amazonaws.com/%s/%s?%s",
$bucket,
$pathToObject,
http_build_query(array(
'AWSAccessKeyId' => $key,
'Expires' => $time,
'Signature' => $signature,
'x-amz-request-payer' => 'requester'
))
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be missing some concepts on what a "[Requester Pays](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RequesterPaysBuckets.html)" bucket does... compared with what you intend, and what your code is doing.

In the code you've posted, ***you* are the requester**, not the person clicking the link.  It's your AWS key and secret that you're using to sign the request, and you would be billed for the downloads.  That doesn't seem like what you intend, but that's what "Requester Pays" buckets do -- they bill the account that owns the AWS key that's used to sign the request.

The `x-amz-request-payer` header is needed so that there's no deception and the requester *knows* that they are paying for the requests they're sending (because they have to add that header for it to work).

So, with a Requester Pays bucket, I could use my AWS key (assuming you granted me permission) and access your resources... and AWS would bill me for the transfers... but there's no "enter your billing information" pop-up that Requester Pays buckets will cause to appear on the screen of someone who wants to download your data.

> Essentially the bucket owner designates the bucket as a Requester Pays bucket, and then requesters add the `x-amz-request-payer=requester` header to the GET requests to indicate that they agree to pay for the data transfer and requests.
>
> <sup>— http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonDevPay/latest/DevPayDeveloperGuide/S3RequesterPays.html</sup>

With all of that said, you can use [Amazon DevPay](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonDevPay/latest/DevPayDeveloperGuide/CreatingYourApp.html) to [sell access to S3 data in a Requester Pays bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonDevPay/latest/DevPayDeveloperGuide/S3RequesterPays.html#DevPayUsingRequesterPaystoSell), but this appears to require you to [develop and register a product](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonDevPay/latest/DevPayDeveloperGuide/RegisteringApp.html) (such as a web app) with DevPay, for which your customers will be billed by Amazon Payments.